# Volume of solid of revolution about the y-axis

Tags: integration

I have to calculate the volume of solid of revolution of $$y = 1 - (x - 2)^2$$ that is sealed off by the x-axis and another point, and rotated about the y-axis. To get the equation in terms of x:

$$(x - 2)^2 = 1 - y$$

If I square root this, do I just take the positive root? So, do I take: $x = 2+\sqrt{1-y}$ and use that in the integral? We were given a tip to use $x = 2-\sqrt{1-y}$, and I'm not sure where that answer came from.

Comment: You have to take both of the equations for $x$ (plus and minus sign), and integrate over both of them. This is because curve is "cut off" at $y=1$. If you plot all of the functions, you will understand.

Comment: When you say integrate over both of them, do you mean find the integrals of both equations for x?

Comment: Yes. You have to choose the integration limits quite carefully.

Comment: I was looking at other examples on here and was wondering if I should only take the positive root because the volume being calculated is in the first quadrant only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint. You should use both roots:
$$\mbox{Volume}=\pi\int_{y=0}^1((2+\sqrt{1-y})^2-(2-\sqrt{1-y})^2)dy=8\pi\int_{0}^1\sqrt{1-y}\,dy.$$

P.S. Note that for $y\in [0,1]$, $0<2-\sqrt{1-y}<2+\sqrt{1-y}$ (their graphs are both in the first quadrant).

Answer (score 0):

There is a much simpler way of solving this problem that avoids all the messiness of solving for $x(y)$ and multiple integrals and so on. That is to use Pappus's $(2^{nd})$ Centroid Theorem: the volume of a planar area of revolution is the product of the area $A$ and the length of the path traced by its centroid $R$, i.e., $2πR$. The bottom line is that the volume is given simply by $V=2πRA$. The centroid (for revolution about the $y$-axis) is given by

$$R=\frac{\int x\cdot y\ dx}{\int y\ dx}=\frac{1}{A}\int x\cdot y\ dx$$

For the problem at hand, where the $x$-axis is the lower bound, you can readily demonstrate that $x\in[1,3]$, so that the area, centroid, and volume are given by

$$
A=\int_1^3 y\ dx=\frac{4}{3}\\
R=\frac{1}{A}\int_1^3 x\cdot y\ dx=2\\
V=2\pi RA=\frac{16\pi}{3}$$